# How can I find the size of a DataTable row in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

Does `DataTable` in C# provide a property that gives me the size of each row (number of bytes)?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "row size"? The size the row *could* have with the data types (ie. a varchar(40) takes 40 or 80 bytes (unicode or not)), or the actual size (an empty string doesn't take any size)?

Comment: yes. Row size of each row in bytes.

Comment: So by "row size" you mean "row size". ok...

Answer (score -3):

You can determine the unmanaged size of a managed object with [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx).

Comment: Nice idea, I didn't know about Marshal.SizeOf() but it doesn't work in this case. I just tried this but it throws an argument exception if you call Marshal.SizeOf() with an argument of type DataRow, with the detail "cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed".